# TableView как выполнить действие до и после сортировки?

Tags: java, javafx

```
@FXML
private TableView<GuestTableModel> tblVisits;
private ObservableList<GuestTableModel> visits = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
 @FXML
 private TableColumn<GuestTableModel, Integer> totalSpendColumn;
 @FXML
 private TableColumn<GuestTableModel, String> firstName;
   public void initialize(){
         totalSpendColumn.setCellValueFactory(param -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(param.getValue().getTotalSpend()));
         totalSpendColumn.setComparator(Integer::compareTo);
         totalSpendColumn.setSortable(true);
         firstName.setCellValueFactory(param -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(param.getValue().getFirstName()));
         firstName.setComparator(Integer::compareTo);
         firstName.setSortable(true);
    }
```

Есть таблица с данными, данных много, поэтому на некоторых компьютерах это может занимать ощутимое время, поэтому хочу в этот момент вывести на экран значёк загрузки.
для этого мне нужно до сортировки включить его, а после отключить. Есть ли такая возможность?

Comment: Компонент TableView имеет метод setOnSort(). Он позволит выполнить действие перед началом сортировки

Comment: Если "это занимает ощутимое время" , то сортировку нужно выполнять в отдельном потоке. А начало выполнения и конец этого потока уже не сложно отследить.